# jQuery function for check textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I’d like use jquery function that validate a input field. This  input field must be used for entering 11 digit numbers that start with 0.
I tried some function but doesn’t work!

```
   function check(mob) {
        var firstnum = mob.substring(1);
        alert(firstnum);
        if (firstnum != "0" || mob.lenght != 11)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? What's the error? (aside: `lenght` is spelled wrong).

Comment: How can I check textbox that all character are digit?

Comment: @NASRIN , you can dot it by getting the parseInt value and comparing it with original if they match all character are number then

Comment: check my answer for more details

Comment: If you want to check is it a digit, try use RegEx

Comment: @WingLeong , ok but how can i use RegEx? Can you take an example?

Comment: I have created an answer using RegEx =)

Comment: @WingLeong Worst. Suggestion. Ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function check(mob) {
    return mob.substring(0, 1) == '0' && mob.length == 11;
}
```

[String Method Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fprototype#Methods)

If you want to check is it 11 digit, you should use RegExp

```
function check(mob) {
    return mob.match(/^0\d{10}$/) != null;
}
```

Comment: `startsWith` is introduced in JavaScript v1.8.6 which my browser doesn't support (yet).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.charAt(0)` to get the first character of a string. `.substring(1)` will return the rest of the string minus the first character.

```
"01234567890".substring(1) = "1234567890"

"01234567890".charAt(0) = "0"

"01234567890".length = 11 (assuming that you have spelled "length" correctly in your code)
```

**Edit:** Since you also need to check for digits, you *could* use a regular expression to verify this (although the *whole check* could also be done with a regex)

The completed function could therefore be simplified to just:

```
function isValidMobile(mobileNumber) {
    return mobileNumber.charAt(0) == 0 && mobileNumber.length === 11 && /^\d+$/.test(mobileNumber);
}
```

Or without the regex

```
function isValidMobile(mobileNumber) {
    return mobileNumber.charAt(0) == 0 && mobileNumber.length === 11 && !isNaN(mobileNumber);
}
```

Comment: you are not validating that all the characters are numbers or not

Comment: @RohitAgrawal Not even giving someone a chance to correct their answer before downvoting is just plain rude

Comment: you are missing the main logic here, update it and i will remove the downvote

Answer (score 0):

```
if (firstnum >= 1 || mob.lenght <= 11)   //lenght  spell wrong
```

change to

```
 if (firstnum >= 1 || mob.length<= 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check(mob) {
  if(!isNaN(mob)){ // or use parseInt
    var firstnum = mob.charAt(0);
    alert(firstnum);

    if (firstnum != "0" || mob.length != 11) {
            return false;
       } else {
            return true;
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give it a try

```
function check(mob) {
    var num = parseInt(mob);
    if (mob+'' == '0'+num  && mob.length == 11)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

here what I am doing is that parseInt will give you exact same number without `0` if all characters are numbers, so in the condition I am just adding `0` in starting and checking with mobile number , it will do 2 validation in once , all are number starts with `0` and next validation is for length

Answer (score 0):

Try using a simple regex as below

```
function check(mob) {
    return /^0\d{10}$/.test(mob)
}
```